# Creating and Adding quick actions for community Users

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, community, lightning-quickaction

How can I create and add the quick actions for Community Users.I am able to create tab  and add it on navigation menu.
But I want to create a quick action and add it to Details page of Object.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in the release notes :https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring16/release-notes/rn_networks_templates_more_record_actions_napili.htm

**Community members with the necessary permissions can follow the record and use the quick actions defined for the object from the record banner on a record detail page. Previously, they could only edit and delete records. You can define the quick actions for each object on the object page layout in Setup, and then assign those layouts to the community user profiles. We recommend including quick actions only for the objects supported on Napili.**

***Custom Visualforce actions aren’t supported.***